# bat file for setting IIS App pool

Tags: batch-file, iis-7

Can i set an Website's App Pool in IIS using the bat file or any other scripts?[image: IIS APP pool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run msdeploy.exe and pass in parameters and set the AppPool as follows something like this:

```
msdeploy.exe 
  -verb:sync -source:appHostConfig="Default Web Site" 
  -enableLink:AppPoolExtension 
  -dest:package=site.zip 
  -declareParam:name="Application Pool",
       defaultValue="Default Web Site",
       description="Application pool for this site",
       kind=DeploymentObjectAttribute,
       scope=appHostConfig,
       match="application/@applicationPool"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell:

```
import-module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' ApplicationPool NewAppPoolName
```